# Accessing Stack Overflow turns into blog.stackoverflow.com

Tags: support, stack-overflow, blog

When I try to access Stack Overflow, I get to the Stack Exchange blog. But the URL is still stackoverflow.com.

When I try to go to my profile page on Stack Overflow, I get a 404 error. Did I do something wrong or is it Stack Overflow?

Comment: Something is seriously broken on your end, it seems.

Comment: What happens when you click a link to it. Like this: http://stackoverflow.com/

Comment: Virus. Worm. Spyware. Malware. Pick one! Oh, also might be userscript/extension/addon specific to your browser. Try different browser.

Comment: @JonW I get to go to blog again.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd How? It worked fine 10 minutes ago?

Comment: @loko virus takes few seconds to infect a computer, same for worms/trojans etc.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I didn't even make any changes to my computer or anything.

Comment: To be more constrictive here: click Start --> cmd --> type `ping stackoverflow.com` and see what you get. You *should* see "Pinging stackoverflow.com [198.252.206.16]...". The IP for http://blog.stackoverflow.com/ is different: 198.252.206.20

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd That is what I am getting...

Comment: OK, another idea: browse to http://198.252.206.16/ - what you see?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd Site not found

Comment: One last thing, try different browser.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd It worked, but still how is it only failing in Firefox?

Comment: @loko "... Oh, also might be userscript/extension/addon specific to your browser..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like the evil work of misbehaving user script, extension or add-on in your browser.

Disable ALL user scripts, extensions and add-ons you have on the misbehaving browser, then turn them on one by one until you find the culprit.